# if statement with SQL

Tags: c#, sql, .net, if-statement

Kind of new to this so you know.

I'm making a Quiz-maker to a school project and when you make the Quiz you get to choose if you want more then one correct answer. And if it is more than one the answer alternatives are supposed to be items in checkboxes else Radiobuttons.

correctAnswer is a bit saved in SQL.

So what I want to do is something like this but if there is any way to say "if it's more then one true answer use CheckBox":

```
var command2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Answer WHERE IdQuestion = @Id", connection);
command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", questionid);

var dataSet = new DataSet();
var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command2);
adapter.Fill(dataSet);

if("correctAnswer" == True)
{
    RadioButtonList.DataSource = dataSet;
    RadioButtonList.DataTextField = "Answer";
    RadioButtonList.DataValueField = "Id";
    RadioButtonList.DataBind();
}
else
{
    CheckBoxList.DataSource = dataSet;
    CheckBoxList.DataTextField = "Answer";
    CheckBoxList.DataValueField = "Id";
    CheckBoxList.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: I get lost about here in your code: `if("correctAnswer" == True)`.  Aren't you emitting the question?  What does `correctAnswer` have to do with it (other than you'd want to count how many there are?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regular C# solution without fancy query:

```
int nCorrect = 0;
foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(row["correctAnswer"]) == true)
        ++nCorrect;

if( nCorrect > 1 )
    //checkbox
else
    //radiobutton
```

Possible LINQ solution:

```
int nCorrect = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Sum(
    r => r.Field<bool>("correctAnswer") == true ? 1 : 0
    );     // ick!
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it before. You will have to fetch the question somewhere.

```
SELECT * FROM question WHERE Id=@Id
```

Replace that with

```
SELECT *,(SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM answer WHERE correctAnswer=1 AND IdQuestion=question.Id) FROM question WHERE Id=@Id
```

and then you have another element in your row which contains whether your question has multiple correct answers or not.

Comment: Might be good to name that expanded term.  Putting it after `select *` (which you seem to be recommending) will make it difficult to know which column number it has.

Answer (score 0):

You can count number of rows in your dataset, to check if it contains more than one correct answer, However as  `ebyrob` i am also lost at `If("correctAnswer" == True)` ,You need to get answers which are correct and then count them.

```
   if(ds !=Null)
   { 
   if(ds.tables[0].Rows.Count>0)
    { 
      if(ds.tables[0].Rows.Count>1)
      {
        //multiple answer question go for CheckBoxList
      }
      else
       {
         // Single correct answer .
       }       

     }
    }
```

Comment: Close, but (s)he didn't constrain to only correct answers in the query.  You'd have to count how many `correctAnswer`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you fill your dataset, query it using linq to see how many correct answers there are.  If it's 1, use radio buttons.  If it's more than 1, use checkboxes.  If it's 0, don't display the question.